# How do i make a galaxy map similiar to this?

Tags: worldbuilding-resources, map-making, galactic

https://i.stack.imgur.com/16dpM.jpg

This is a star wars galaxy map i found. I have inkarnate but i dont think its possible to make a galaxy map like this on it.If anyone knows of any tutorials that could help me make something like this i'd appareciate it.

Edit: I actually figured it out on my own. Apparently you can just use inkarnate.Thanks to all those who commented.

Comment: Relevant: that map was posted on reddit by someone who said it's a drawing made in Photoshop. https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWars/comments/68f558/star_wars_galaxy_map_i_made_to_learn_some/

Comment: Also, for info, that's definitely not the [Milky Way](https://astronomy.nju.edu.cn/xtzl/EN/index.html), note the weird diagonal "spokes".

Comment: I haven't looked at all the options myself, but you could check out what we have in our [list of worldbuilding resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/143607/40609). If you don't find something that can help you out there, do please let us know if you find an appropriate tool! Indeed, the answer is a community wiki, please add the resource. Thanks!

Comment: The lines on the map are trade routes. This look basically like an subway/underground map on a spacy background.  Try https://metromapmaker.com/

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, then accept it with the checkmark.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. "*definitely not the Milky Way*". I should HOPE not. OP explicitly states it is "*a star wars galaxy map*". Film credits do say " a long time ago IN A GALAXY FAR,FAR AWAY"

Answer (score 5):

**Pencil-n-Paper 1.0**

There's nothing wrong with drawing the starry heavens that inhabit your imagination on a piece of paper, you know!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the lines you see on that map are "trade routes" but even if they are something else, they remind me of an underground/subway map with systems as stations. All framed on a space gas background.

There is a free tool you can use to draw these kinds of subway maps. I'm guessing there are others but you might start with: https://metromapmaker.com/